# Who was William Hooper, eponym of "Hooper's Paradox"?

Tags: biographical-details

"Hooper's Paradox" is the name given by Martin Gardner (in his Mathematics, Magic and Mystery of 1956) to the apparent paradox that you can apparently dissect a $3 \times 10$ rectangle into a $2 \times 6$ and a $4 \times 5$ rectangle.

The resolution is obvious:[image: Hooper's Paradox]

This was the basis of Sam Loyd's famous missing square puzzle, which has been widely propagated since the beginning of the 20th century.

My question: who was William Hooper? All I know is that he was the author of
*Rational Recreations* (4 Volumes, 1774, 2nd edition 1782-3).

There is a contemporaneous William Hooper who was active in the American Revolutionary War, but it can't be the same bloke because he that William Hooper was somewhat busy dodging redcoats at that time.

Can anyone find out such things as his date and place of birth, and what he did?

Comment: A more detailed citation for the puzzle in the question: "Rational Recreation CVI: The geometric money" in W. Hooper, *Rational Recreations, Vol. IV, 4ᵗʰ edition*, London: B. Law and Son 1794, pp. 286-287 ([Google scan](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Rational_Recreations_The_Third_Edition_C/z3PEZySNOB8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA286&printsec=frontcover))

Answer (score 4):

I have not been able to find out much other than that William Hooper was a translator of contemporary German and French publications:

1. *Letters of Baron Bielfeld: Containing Original Anecdotes of the Prussian Court for the last Twenty Years*, 4 volumes, London 1768-1770.
2. Jakob Friedrich Freiherr von Bielfeld, *The Elements of Universal Erudition*, 3 volumes, London 1770. (original work: *Les premiers traits de l'erudition universelle; ou, Analyse abregée de toutes les sciences, des beaux-arts et des belles lettres*, 1767).
3. Louis Sébastien Mercier, *Memoirs of the Year Two Thousand Five Hundred*, 2 volumes, London 1772 (original work: *L'An Deux Mille Quatre Cent Quarante*, 1771).
4. Salomon Gessner, *New Idylls*, London 1776 (original work: *Neue Idyllen*, 1772).
5. Claude Adrien Helvetius, *A Treatise on Man, His Intellectual Faculties and His Education*, 2 volumes, London 1777 (original work: *De l'homme, de ses facultés intellectuelles et de son éducation*, 1773).

No. 2 is significant in that it contains -- according to the Oxford English Dictionary -- the earliest known occurrence of the word "statistics". I also note that the translator of No. 1 is identified as "Mr. Hooper", whereas the translator of all other works is identified as "W. Hooper, M.D.". This *may* suggest that William Hooper was born around 1745.

I notice that No. 4 was "printed for S. Hooper". This is the publisher [Samuel Hooper](https://www.britishmuseum.org/collection/term/BIOG148211) (1733-1793), who was, based on searching Google Books, active between 1756 and 1792. I can find no evidence that the two men were related, though.